# Punctured neighborhood theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let   $X$ be a complex Banach space and let $T$ be a bounded linear operator acting on $X.$ Consider a   subspace  $M$ (not necessarily closed) such that $T(M)\subset M,$ $T(X)+M=X$ and there exists  $\epsilon>0$ such that $T-\lambda I$ is injective and  $M\subset (T-\lambda I)(X)$ for all $0<|\lambda|<\epsilon.$
I showed, using the fact that $T(X)+M=X,$ that there  exists $\epsilon\geq\epsilon^{'}>0$ such that $(T-\lambda I)(X)+\overline{M}=X,$ where $\overline{M}$ is the closure subset of $M.$ And hence the operator $(T-\lambda I)$ is injective and with a dense image.    My question is, is there  $\epsilon^{''}>0$ such that $(T-\lambda I)(X)$ is closed?